# Runspaces and Shared Objects with Methods

Tags: multithreading, powershell, runspace

There are lots of QA's and articles online explaining how to work with runspaces and shared objects' data in PowerShell using synchronization, locking, etc. But I couldn't find anything about executing method of `PSObject`, passed by `[reference]` from the main thread to another runspace. When called from within the runspace, I found that the method of the passed object executes on the *main* thread.

Is there a way to make the method run in the runspace, other than rewriting it as a separate function and adding that function to the runspace via `[powershell]::Create().AddScript()`?